# Name for using verb with different meanings for parts of its compound object

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a name for a construction where a verb has different meanings for different parts of its compound object?

For example:

"John likes to make friends, and paper airplanes."

I'm not sure this is strictly grammatically correct, I understand it's used more for humour than clarity or correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **zeugma**.

> She left in a huff and a taxi

is a modern version of the classic example

> She left in a huff and a sedan chair

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis) there is a related idea of a **syllepsis**; A zeugma being a specialised form of syllepsis.